# How does MongoDB distribute data across a cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I've read about sharding a collection in MongoDB. MongoDB lets me shard a collection explicitly by calling `shardCollection` method. There I can choose whether I want it to be rangely shareded or hashingly sharded.

My question is, what would happen if I didn't call the `shardCollection` method, and I had say 100 nodes?

Would MongoDB keep the collections intact and distribute them across the cluster?

Would MongoDB keep all the collections in a single node?

Do I completely not understand how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database can have a mixture of sharded and unsharded collections. Sharded collections are partitioned and distributed across shards in the cluster. As at MongoDB 3.4, each database has a primary shard where the unsharded collections are stored. If your deployment has a number of databases this may result in some distribution of unsharded collections, but there is no balancing activity for unsharded data. For more information on expected behaviours, see the [Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) section in the MongoDB manual.

If you are interested in distribution of unsharded collections within a sharded database, there is a relevant feature request you can watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue tracker: [SERVER-939: Ability to distribute collections in a single DB](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-939).